# How do i make WordPress return 404 instead of redirecting on misspelled page?

Tags: redirect, 404-error

In a vanilla wordpress install, a misspelled page such as `https://example.com/weclome` leads to a 404 error, which is fine.

However, once I set custom permalinks for posts such as `https://example.com/data/%postname%/` , the very same misspelled link `https://example.com/weclome` no longer 404s, but sends a 301 redirect to the start page `https://example.com/` .

I have deactivated all plugins, the problem persists.

I tried:

`remove_action('template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect');`

`remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');`

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'no_redirect_on_404');
function no_redirect_on_404($redirect_url)
{
    if (is_404()) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

`add_filter( 'do_redirect_guess_404_permalink', '__return_false' );`

in functions.php, none of which works.

How can I have custom permalinks as shown, and still have misspelled or unknown pages 404 instead of 301 redirect?

Comment: Your start page, what's its slug?

Comment: @TomJNowell The start page slug is `hello`.